# Sorting a file and putting them in different files

Tags: linux, sorting, text, process

I am trying to sort a file that has different genomic regions, and each region has a letter&number combination to itself.

I want to sort the whole file in terms of each genomic location `(columns1,2,3)`,and if these 3 are the same,
and extract it into a new separate file.

My input is:

```
1.txt
chr1    10  20 . . 00000 ACTGBACA
chr1    10  20 . + 11111 AACCCCHQ
chr1    18  40 . . 0 AA12KCCHQ
chr7    22  23 . . 21 KLJMWQKD
chr7    22  23 . . 8 XJKFIRHFBF24
chrX    199 201 . . KK AVJI24
```

What I am expecting is:

```
chr1.10-20.txt
chr1    10  20 ACTGBACA
chr1    10  20 AACCCCHQ


chr1.18-40.txt
chr1    18  40 AA12KCCHQ

chr7.22-23.txt
chr7    22  23 KLJMWQKD
chr7    22  23 XJKFIRHFBF24

chrX.199-201.txt
chrX    199 201 AVJI24
```

I was experimenting splitting a document with `awk`, but it is not what I want to do.

```
awk -F, '{print > $1$2$3".txt"}' 1.txt
```

It gives me the file names with all the rows, and inside the files, it is again the whole row, even though I need only column 1,2,3 and 7.

```
>ls
1.txt                                  
chr1    10  20 . + 11111 AACCCCHQ.txt  
chr7    22  23 . . 21 KLJMWQKD.txt     
chrX    199 201 . . KK AVJI24.txt  
chr1    10  20 . . 00000 ACTGBACA.txt  
chr1    18  40 . . 0 AA12KCCHQ.txt     
chr7    22  23 . . 8 XJKFIRHFBF24.txt   

>cat chr1\ \ \ \ 10\ \ 20\ .\ +\ 11111\ AACCCCHQ.txt 
chr1    10  20 . + 11111 AACCCCHQ
```

I would appreciate if you can show me how to fix the file names and its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT="$1"

while read -r LINE; do
    GEN_LOC="$(echo "$LINE" | tr -s ' ' '.' | cut -d '.' -f 1,2,3)"
    echo "$LINE" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,6,7 >> "${GEN_LOC}.txt"
done < "$INPUT"
```

This script will take an input file in the format you posted and read it in line-by-line. For each line, it will replace the extra whitespace with dots for the filename and cut it down to fields 1, 2, and 3 (storing it in the `$GEN_LOC` variable). Then, it will append the whole `$LINE` to a file named `${GEN_LOC}.txt`. If there are multiple lines that end up outputting to the same filename, that's fine - the line will just append. This does not take into account previous runs, so if you run this twice, it will continually append to the existing files. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work with the '.'. And 'line 3: syntax error at or near while'

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you using bash or some other shell?

Comment: I am using bash and running this script as : awk awkscript.awk 1.txt , and it gives me these commented above errors

Comment: Ahh, I see. This is not an awk script, this is a Bash script. You can save the above as `script.sh` for instance, make it executable by running `chmod +x script.sh`, then run it with `script.sh 1.txt`. Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit my answer to include a shebang.

Comment: Thank you!! It names the files very well!! However, it does not select the columns inside of the file. It print the whole line inside ( head chr1.18.40.txt :
chr1    18  40 . . 0 AA12KCCHQ
)

Comment: I didn't notice you changed your input file. Okay, so you're trying to output columns 1, 2, 3, 6, and 7?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159945/discussion-between-john-moon-and-bapors).